# Geometric way to show the value of integral

Tags: integration

$g$ is a strictly increasing continuous function mapping $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. What is the geometric argument showing $\int_0^1 g(x)dx + \int_0^1 g^{-1}(u)du=1$?

I know that if the area under the graph g and $g^{-1}$ is the same because I can get one of them by reflecting the other one. However, I don't know how to show the latter part of the question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the curve $y=g(x)$ from the conditions given, $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$. In the rectangle $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ the area under the curve $y=g(x)$ and the $x-$axis is the lower portion of the rectangle and the area under the curve and the $y-$axis is the upper portion of this rectangle. The sum of the two areas is the area of the rectangle which is $1$.

Comment: What is $u$ in this question? Just another variable other than x?

Comment: @J.doe $u$ is just the variable for integration.  To interpret the integral $\int_0^1g^{-1}(u) \, du$, think of viewing the area from the $y-$axis.

Comment: why can't x be used?

Comment: @J.doe perhaps if you look at the picture in the following link it will help you understand better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions